# Galaxy fame wont work with otg

Tags: 4.1-jelly-bean

I am trying to operate an otg cabe with my Galaxy fame but am getting nowhere. When I run host diagnostic it doesnt recognise the phone Anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

[According to GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/samsung_galaxy_fame_s6810-5279.php), this phone doesn't support USB-on-the-go.